# Publication Workflow

Tags: workflow

I am looking into having the two following roles:

1. Editor
2. Publisher

and the following different states a post can be in:

1. Draft
2. Ready for publication
3. Published

The workflow I am seeking is:

1. An **editor** writes a blogpost. It is a **draft**.
2. Once it is final, the editor marks ist as **ready for publication**. From that moment on, the editor **looses the ability to edit the blogpost**.
3. The **publisher** reviews, edits and **publishes the blogpost**.

Is this possible with Wordpress?
If not, is there a state of the art plugin for such a workflow?
It seems like an obvious workflow.

Comment: As I have less than 300 points in reputation, I could not add the "publication" tag to the post. Could someone do this (if it makes sense)?

Comment: "publication" is not a very descriptive tag. "workflow" is just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow me to translate the roles and states into WP parlance:

Roles:

1. Editor -> Author
2. Publisher -> Editor

States:

1. Draft -> Draft
2. Ready for publication -> Pending Review
3. Published -> Published

The only thing you need a plugin for is this bit:

"From that moment on, the *author* looses the ability to edit the blogpost."